# How to find the count of empty space expressions in column values?

Tags: sql

if you have

```
e_id ename 
1 hansen sahul 
2 dennis richard rathore
```

how to find the ename count of e_id 1 as ? 2

how to find the ename count of e_id 2 as ? 3

Comment: Such table do not follow 1NF and should be normalized.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the string manipulation functions vary between databases, so I can give SQL Server dialect. If you're using a different database, you'll have to find the replacements for [`LEN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190329.aspx) and [`REPLACE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862):

```
declare @Names table (e_id int,ename varchar(3000))
insert into @Names (e_id, ename) values
(1,'hansen sahul'),
(2,'dennis richard rathore')

select e_id,LEN(ename) - LEN(REPLACE(ename,' ','')) + 1 as namecount
from @Names
```

Result:

```
e_id        namecount
----------- -----------
1           2
2           3
```

This works be calculating the difference in length between the plain string, and the same string where spaces have been removed. This is logically equivalent to the number of spaces in the string. We then add `1` to match your desired result (the number of names, rather than the number of spaces).

(The table setup is also dialect, but just there to help create a working script)

Comment: If possible, one should canonicalize white space first (how would depend on your RDBMS), so that you would not get bad results if you had two spaces or a space at the beginning or end.

Comment: @ctrahey - Yes, many other cleanup operations may also be required (e.g. there could be other whitespace characters rather than just space). OTOH, maybe we're lucky and the OP already have a good `CHECK` constraint preventing such values from appearing in the table. :-)